# Wordpress on IIS gives HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

Tags: wordpress, iis

I just installed Wordpress on a Windows 2016 Server. I'm using IIS as the webserver for this and created the web site on port 81. It runs fine locally (http://localhost:81), but when I'm accessing the site outside of the server (from my laptop: http://servername:81) I'm getting

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be
>   served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a
>   script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME
>   map.

both in Edge and Chrome.

I added the FastCGI handler mapping in IIS.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Regards,
Nils

Comment: Check server Eventviewer for error logs

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your web.config
Check if enable "URL REWRITE v1.1"

Comment: I have installed URL rewrite 2.1. I took the config for web.config from https://gist.github.com/adilmughal/6388876.

Answer (score 0):

I went to through all the content of my site and there were some references to localhost instead of the server name. That's why these resources couldn't be resolved.